# Deploying GWT application to Godaddy

Tags: gwt, external

I have read through all I can find but doesn't just work out for me.
Does anyone by chance know a detailed step-by-step instruction to deploy GWT to external domain servers like Godaddy?

I am using maven to manage my app. I can run it in dev mode but when I try to copy over to tomcat, does not work.

Please help.

Comment: I'm a bit biased... but have you considered using a cloud hosting platform like [heroku](http://java.heroku.com/)? They have [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/java) and might be more in line with hosting a java app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more and more attempts leading to frustrations, I decided to host my GWT app on GAE (Google app Engine). It is easier to deploy to GAE  than trying to setup GWT to work on Godaddy services.

And for mvn related issues, I recreated my app using GWT Maven Archetype version 2.3.0-1

I pop the .war in webapps directory of tomcat and voila ... It works

Cheers
PB